# Async/Await uploadTask

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

How can I await uploadTask so I can upload the image/file and track its progress first before inserting download url dan document to firestore,

Following code is my sample Vue project. It works properly, but see the `if (portraitFile)`, it has to be within the condition that I have to upload an image, what if I don't want to upload an image?

It has to move outside that conditional `if`, but it will executed asynchronously before the file finish and download URL retrieved.

*GOAL: Move firestore add() outside uploadTask's finish callback/argument.*

```
    async commitCharacter() {
      try {
        let character = this.character;
        let portraitFile = this.portraitFile;

        if (portraitFile) {
          const uploadTask = storageRef
            .child(`characters/${character.id}/portrait.png`)
            .put(portraitFile, { contentType: "image/png" });

          await uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            snapshot => {
              this.portraitUploadProgress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
            },
            null,
            async () => {
              character.portraitUrl = await storageRef
                .child(`characters/${character.id}/portrait.png`)
                .getDownloadURL();

              if (character.id) {
              await db
                .collection("characters")
                .doc(character.id)
                .update(character);
              } else {
                character.id = (await 
                db.collection("characters").add(character)).id;
              }

              $("#manageCharacter").modal("hide");
            }
          );
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can wrap your `uploadTask` in a promise:

```
async function uploadTaskPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    const storageRef = storage.ref(YOUR_STORAGE_PATH)
    const uploadTask = storageRef.put(YOUR_FILE_OR_BLOB)
    uploadTask.on('state_changed',
      function(snapshot) {
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        console.log('Upload is ' + progress + '% done')
      },
      function error(err) {
        console.log('error', err)
        reject()
      },
      function complete() {
        uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
          resolve(downloadURL)
        })
      }
    )
  })
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const storageUrl = await uploadTaskPromise()
console.log(storageUrl) // do whatever you want with the URL...
```