# Async wait is not working when calling a function

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-promise

```
var value = await this.upload();
if (value == true) {
  this.item.photos = this.uploaded;
  this.item.price = null;
  this.item.qty = null;
  this.dataSrv.addItem(this.item)
    .then(() => {
      this.dataSrv.stopLoading();
      this.dataSrv.toast('Item Added Successfully');
      this.item = {} as Item;
      this.pictures = ['', '', '', ''];
      this.uploaded = [];
      this.photos = ['', '', '', ''];
    })
    .catch(err => {
      this.dataSrv.stopLoading();
      this.dataSrv.toast('Error While Adding Item. Try Again Later');
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

In the above code I am calling upload function to upload picture to Google storage and I am waiting so I can add the image links to uploaded array which will save it to this.item.photos but It does not wait and it directly execute the true condition.

```
async upload(image?) {
  var counter = 0;
  this.pictures.forEach(i => {
    if (i != '') {
      let temp: string = (i) as string;
      temp = temp.replace("data:image/jpg;base64, ", '');
      temp = temp.replace("data:image/jpg;base64,", '');
      temp = temp.replace('must use [property]=binding:', '');
      temp = temp.replace('SafeValue', '');
      temp = temp.replace('(see https://g.co/ng/security#xss)', '');
      const randomId = Math.random().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36) + Math.random().toString(36);
      const uploadTask = this.storage.ref('items/').child(randomId).putString(temp, 'base64', {
        contentType: 'image/png'
      });
      uploadTask
        .then(response => {
          console.log("uploaded");
          console.log(response);
          this.storage.ref('items/' + randomId).getDownloadURL().subscribe(url => {
            this.uploaded.push(url);
            counter++;
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log('not uploaded');
        });
    }
  });
  if (counter != this.uploaded.length) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

I have tried to do return type of Promise in the upload function but nothing changed
I have also tried to do the then after the function call but the same issue happen

**Note that pictures array contains base64 image**

Comment: I think you should return a promise in your `upload` function. or else you won't wait for `uploadTask` to terminate.

Comment: I have tried it as async upload(image?) : Promise<any> but it still not waiting

Comment: it seems to return an uploadTask, which is not a promise, you'll have to wrap it in a promise.  : [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53156127/async-await-uploadtask)

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions will not block by themselves. The issue is that the `forEach` is called synchronously, but it contains code which will run asynchrnously.

A common pattern for doing this:

```js
async upload(image) {
  // use .map instead of .forEach
  // from the callback function we return a Promise, so the result would be
  // an array of promises
  const promises = this.pictures.map(i => {
    // your logic here
    // you must return the promise
    return uploadTask
        .then(response => { /* ... */ })
        .catch(() => { /* ... */ });
  })

  // Wait for all promises to be resolved.
  // Note for the future: Promise.all will reject if at least 1 promise rejects.
  // Your code seems to handle this case and converts a failed Promise into a success inside of `.catch` above.
  await Promise.all(promises);

  // here, the counter should be correct
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Promise.all` will work with objects other than promises ? (A then-able object is enough?)

Comment: @XouDo Promise.all works in mysterious ways :) - try in your browser console: `Promise.all([1,2]).then(result => console.log(result))`. It will log `[1, 2]`. Those aren't promises, but `Promise.all` resolves them as successful.

Comment: You're right, I tried it and most importantly, it works with a handmade thenable object too.

Comment: I am still having the same issue .. I have edit my code to the above code and I have do a then after Promise.all(promises) and it does not work too